# Android Studio open my project in protect mode

Tags: flutter, android-studio

When I pull the (flutter)project and open it in Android Studio, it automatically goes into protection mode and I can't make any changes to my project files.

I tried running `flutter doctor`, `flutter clean`, and `invalidate and reset`, as well as removing the `.idea`, `.build`, and `.gradle` folders.